# Create <div> and append <div> dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a `<div>` dynamically, with an appended `<div>` inside. I have this so far which works:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

I am just having trouble creating and appending the second div to the first div.

I essentially want to do this as the final markup:

```
<div id="block" class="block">
   <div class="block-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an odd way of getting the body element... just use `document.body`.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Use the same process. You already have the variable `iDiv` which still refers to the original element `<div id='block'>` you've created. You just need to create another `<div>` and call `appendChild()`.

```
// Your existing code unmodified...
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

// Now create and append to iDiv
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Sup/1/

The order of event creation doesn't have to be as I have it above. You can alternately append the new `innerDiv` to the outer div before you add both to the `<body>`.

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';

// Create the inner div before appending to the body
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';

// The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

// Then append the whole thing onto the body
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

Comment: can also shorten last line with:
document.body.appendChild(iDiv);

Answer (score 12):

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

var div2 = document.createElement('div');

div2.className = 'block-2';
iDiv.appendChild(div2);
```

Comment: you have pretty much copied Michael Berkowski

Comment: I don't think I could have done that. Simple solutions usually have low variance :D.

Answer (score 4):

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    jDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
jDiv.className = 'block-2';
iDiv.appendChild(jDiv);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.id = 'block';
  iDiv.className = 'block';
  document.body.appendChild(iDiv);

  var iiDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iiDiv.className = 'block-2';

  var s = document.getElementById('block');
  s.appendChild(iiDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know how dynamic this is is, but sometimes this might save your debugging life:

```
var daString="<div id=\'block\' class=\'block\'><div class=\'block-2\'></div></div>";
var daParent=document.getElementById("the ID of whatever your parent is goes in here");
daParent.innerHTML=daString;
```

"Rat javascript" If I did it correctly. Works for me  directly when the div and contents are not themselves dynamic of course, or you can even manipulate the string to change that too, though the string manipulating is complex than the "element.property=bla" approach, this gives some very welcome flexibility, and is a great debugging tool too :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=0,length=2;

     for(i; i<=length;i++)
 {
  $('#footer-div'+[i]).append($('<div class="ui-footer ui-bar-b ui-footer-fixed slideup" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" role="contentinfo" ><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Advertisement </h3></div>')); 

 }
```

Comment: might have been nice to indicate you were using a JavaScript library and that your example uses different markup than the original question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrayDiv = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i <= 1; i++){
        arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
        arrayDiv[i].id = 'block' + i;
        arrayDiv[i].className = 'block' + i;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(arrayDiv[0].appendChild(arrayDiv[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';

var iDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
iDiv2.className = "block-2";

iDiv.appendChild(iDiv2);
// Append to the document last so that the first append is more efficient.
document.body.appendChild(iDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(i<10){
               $('#Postsoutput').prepend('<div id="first'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
               /* get the dynamic Div*/
               $('#first'+i).hide(1000);
               $('#first'+i).show(1000);
                i++;
                }
```