# Jquery append div to new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to append 2 div to new div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#table-filter_wrapper" ).append($( "<div class='main_tbl_btm_info'></div>" ));
            $( "#table-filter_info" ).appendTo( $( ".main_tbl_btm_info" ));
            $( "#table-filter_paginate" ).appendTo( $( ".main_tbl_btm_info" ));
        });
</script>
```

The problem is that it can't find *table-filter_wrapper* at ready.
When I use alert before append then it works.
How can I get that *table-filter_wrapper* is loaded or not.

Comment: Do you know *when* `#table-filter_wrapper` is injected into the DOM?

Comment: @David table-filter_wrapper is loaded at the ready and it take time so when code run it could not find table-filter_wrapper if we give some delay like by alert or other then it works .So actual problem is find table-filter_wrapper is loaded or not after load execute the code.

Comment: How are you "loading" the `#table-filter_wrapper`? At some point, you must be using `append` or similar, so just place this code after the append has been made.

Comment: @David #table-filter_wrapper is created by datatable for pagination and it is loaded on ready and I am using append after init the datatable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create <div> and append <div> dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

you need to delete `$` from your `append` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#table-filter_wrapper" ).append( "<div class='main_tbl_btm_info'></div>");
            $( "#table-filter_info" ).appendTo(".main_tbl_btm_info" );
            $( "#table-filter_paginate" ).appendTo( ".main_tbl_btm_info");
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn’t make sense... `appendTo` can take a jQuery array as argument, so this wouldn’t solve anything.

Comment: but the div is not array in op question.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan yea, the script can’t find `table-filter_wrapper` at ready, which would have nothing to do with your solution.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I don't think that is the problem, `$( "<div class='main_tbl_btm_info'></div>" )` creates a new dom element and it will be accepted by jQuery

Comment: yes from david fiddle I saw it's working and it does make sense, but it doesn't mean that this is right to be done with elements already declared or being passed from other sources.

Comment: @all my actual problem is table-filter_wrapper take time to load if we add an alert before append it take time and my code is working good but if we remove alert then it could not find table-filter_wrapper so i want to know when table-filter_wrapper is loaded.

Comment: @Prince - then check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592493/check-if-element-exists-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works if the elements are available in the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/XY7Sf/

```
<div id="table-filter_wrapper"></div>
<div id="table-filter_info"></div>
<div id="table-filter_paginate"></div>
```

If they are not available in the DOM, you need to run this code **when** they are, maybe in an ajax callback somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try to target a wrapper div first or table and the use .find() to get the class you want to appentTo like:

```
var a = $(".wrapper").find(".main_tbl_btm_info")
$( "#table-filter_paginate" ).appendTo(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this, right ?

**Demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Y97cn/)**

JS:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#table-filter_wrapper" ).append($( "<div class='main_tbl_btm_info'>main_tbl_btm_info</div>" ));

    $( ".main_tbl_btm_info" ).append($( "<div id='table-filter_info'>table-filter_info</div>" ));

    $( ".main_tbl_btm_info" ).append($( "<div id='table-filter_paginate'>table-filter_paginate</div>" ));
```

});