# Div Increment on button click

Tags: javascript

Need javascript for incrementation...

I have two  with class names, parent and child (child inside the parent).

Each  has a button outside them. If I click the button outside the parent, the div should be incremented with child inside it.

And if the button outside the child is clicked, the child div must be incremented.

Find the below link as demo.
[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/1/)

HTML code is

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
     </div><br>
     <a href="#" class="inc-child">Add one more child</a>
</div><br>
<a href="#" class="inc-parent">Add one more Parent</a>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far??? Show your effort.

Comment: What do you mean by incremented?

Comment: Hope this helps "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically"

Comment: @Gustavo, go to the link I posted. You'll understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a click handlers with event delegation and cloning like below

```
jQuery(function($){
    var _parent = $('.parent').eq(0).clone();
    $(document).on('click', '.inc-child', function(){
        var $p = $(this).parent();    
        $p.find('.child').first().clone().insertBefore(this)
    })
    $('.inc-parent').on('click', function(){
        _parent.clone().insertBefore(this)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9uLdd7r4/)

Comment: Could you please update the script for remove also ??

http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JS](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/4dEsJ/67/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button[name='addDom']").click(function() {
    var domElement = $('<div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item"><img src="images/i-5.png" alt="Sweep Stakes" /></div></div>');
    $(this).after(domElement);
});

});
```

Comment: Could you implement this code in the link I posted ??