# How to create 50 divs in container Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have some problem.  Me need to create dynamically - 40 div's in one container by Javascript (div also).  Like a calendar days in calendar . Please help ! Don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried? Have any code?

Comment: `var container = document.getElementById("contianer"); for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) { var child = document.createNode("div"); container.appendChild(child) }`

Comment: Ohhhh.... thanks a lot ))  It worked!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically) question:

Code from the answer (modified):

```
//Your existing div
var divP = document.getElementById('divParent');

// Now create and append to divP
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDiv.className = 'innerDiv';

// Append it to the parent div
iDiv.appendChild(divP);

//Repeat it 40 times...
```

Also check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) tutorial for appendChild out