# innerHtml cannot print my div inside another

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue that I've never encountered before. I would like simply to add a div inside another. I test using the developer console first. 
I get the element in which I want to include the another div and it prints the element correctly in the console.
Then I do the following:

```
document.getElementById("ctiGlobalContainer").innerHtml += '<div id="ctiContentPanel" state="displayed" style="z-index: 10000;right: 0;top: 50px;height: 100%;width: 200px;position: fixed;margin: 0;"></div>'
```

I get the following result:

```
"undefined<div id="ctiContentPanel" state="displayed" style="z-index: 10000;right: 0;top: 50px;height: 100%;width: 200px;position: fixed;margin: 0;"></div>"
```

Why is the ***undefined*** showing ? And the div is not included in the dom...

Comment: It's not a best way to add HTML in your page with innerHTML, use jQuery or, see `.appendChild()` function : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

The property is called `innerHTML`.

`innerHtml` starts out undefined.

`+=` converts that to a string and then appends to it.

When you convert `undefined` to a string you get `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in there. Please instead of `innerHtml` use `innerHTML`. **Javascript** is not recognizing `innerHtml` as its property that is why the code in there is showing `undefined`.