# I could not get table dynamically in the same page in JavaScript when I click on different sizes of table button like 3*3 ,5*5

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function boardSize() {
  var rows = 3;

  var cols = 3;
  document.write("   <table>   ");
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");

    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      var btncolo;
      var btnarr = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
      btncolo = btnarr[x - 1];

      var stringArray = ["<td><input type='button' style=backgroundcolor:'", btncolo, "' onclick='hitheadr('id')'>  </td>"];
      document.write(stringArray.join(""));
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("    </table>");
}
```

I have been trying with this for displaying table in the same page but I could not get the result.

I know the reason that I am using `document.write()` gives the result in other page.

What can I use to get the desired result?

Comment: You can use this as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You could create DOM elements and append it to the body, instead of writing it to the document, possibly after loading the page, which leads to strange results.

Some helpful methods:

- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for creating elements, like `table`, `tr`, `td`, `button`
- [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) for a simple text
- [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) this add the node to the end of a parent node

```js
function hitheadr(id) {
    return function () {
        console.log(id);
    };
}

function createTable(rows, cols, element) {
    function getButtonId(i, j) {
        return 'button' + i + '|' + j
    }

    var table = document.createElement('table'),
        tr, td, button, i, j,
        colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            button = document.createElement('button');
            button.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getButtonId(i, j)));
            button.onclick = hitheadr(getButtonId(i, j));
            button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
            td.appendChild(button);
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    element.appendChild(table);
}

createTable(3, 3, document.body);
```