# How do i append a div using javascript and not jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I used a query selector to get the div i want to append. But the created div doesn't want to append to anything other than the body. Is there a way i can make it specifically append under the div?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create <div> and append <div> dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004117/create-div-and-append-div-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp
What you need to do is

```
parent.appendChild(thatDiv);
```