# How to display non-repetitive letter within 3 boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

The below code can display a single random letter in each box. However, a letter should not be able to appear on different boxes at the same time as one of the boxes. For example, box 1 displays "A", then box 2 and 3 cannot display "A" also.

```
        function random() {
        var letter = [];
        for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {
            letter.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
        }
    
        return letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * letter.Length)];
      }
  
        function display()
        {
                document.getElementById("box1").textContent = random();
                document.getElementById("box2").textContent = random();
                document.getElementById("box3").textContent = random(); 
        }
```

Comment: Since you're just making an array and picking from it any of the 'get random elements from array without repeats' duplicates will work for you. [How to efficiently randomly select array item without repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891173/how-to-efficiently-randomly-select-array-item-without-repeats), [How to get a number of random elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269545/how-to-get-a-number-of-random-elements-from-an-array) etc. (but i wonder why you build the array every call instead of just generating a random number between 65 and 91)

Comment: also see: [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to overhaul your `random` function to generate all the letters at once, like so:

```js
function randomN(n=3) {
  const letters = new Set()
  while (letters.size < 3) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (91-65)) + 65
    letters.add(String.fromCharCode(i))
  }
  return [...letters]
}

function display() {
  const [letter1, letter2, letter3] = randomN()
  document.getElementById("box1").textContent = letter1
  document.getElementById("box2").textContent = letter2
  document.getElementById("box3").textContent = letter3
}
```

For a more modern approach you can utilize generators:

```js
function* randomLetters() {
  const letters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM".split('')
  while (letters.length > 0) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)
    yield letters[i]
    letters.splice(i, 1)
  }
}

function display() {
  const letters = randomLetters()
  document.getElementById("box1").textContent = letters.next()
  document.getElementById("box2").textContent = letters.next()
  document.getElementById("box3").textContent = letters.next()
  /* and so on and so forth! */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function letterGenerator(n=1) {
    var generated_letters = [];
    var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''); 
      
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++){     
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);              
       var letter = alphabet.splice(random, 1)[0];
        generated_letters.push(letter)
    }
    return generated_letters;
}

var letters = letterGenerator(3)
```

gives `Array(3) [ "Q", "T", "I" ]`, for example.

**by using `splice`, we are making sure the randomly chosen letters are removed from the `alphabet` variable.**

you can then go over the letters with `for (letter of letters)` or something like that, and add each one to the desired element.

by the way, maybe [run](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-all-elements-by-id-starting-with) a `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="box"]');` to get all elements and add to them with a for loop.

this, alongside the `n` parameter, allows for any number of generated letters.

(if you really want it to be generic, [create](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004145/4935162) the box elements using js as well)

the solutions attached in the comments are certainly clever.
I especially liked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38571132/4935162)